# Email encoding using Django

Tags: python, django, encoding, html-email

My webapp stores Hebrew text in a Postgres DB and later sends it as an email.
I can see that the text is stored well in the DB, but when sent as an email it look like gibberish:

> ×¢×•×‘×“ ×™×§×¨, ×–×”×• ×˜×¡×˜ ×©×œ ×”×”×ª×¨××•×ª ×”× ×©×œ×—×•×ª
>   ×‘×¢×‘×¨×™×ª.

I'm using urlllib to unquote the text from the DB

```
urllib.unquote(text)
```

and EmailSender to send the email:

```
EmailSender().send_html(
    "my email subject",
    email_content,
    [email],
    headers=headers,
    fail_silently=True
)
```

What can be causing that?

Comment: Is there any specific motive for use of **urllib**?

Comment: Which [encoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html) are you using with your Postgres DB?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably happening because the source text is in UTF-8, not in ASCII.

You should take a look at [Useful utility functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#useful-utility-functions).

There you will find the `smart_text()` method, which I think will solve your problem by converting your `email_content`.

---

You could also use the encode/decode approach.

Read [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) and try:

`email_content.encode("your_encoding").decode("utf-8")`