# Django's send_mail doesn't send non-ascii symbols like cyrillic

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send like this:

```py
send_mail(u'Тема', u'Тело письма', EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['EMAIL_RECIEVER'])
```

But get something like this instead:

"SСѓР±СЊРµРєС‚" as subject and "РўРµР»Рѕ РїРёСЃСЊРјР°" as body of message.

How should I send those kinds of mails?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035666/email-encoding-using-django

Answer (score 0):

Try this (my answer may be not working, just hopin' for good luck):

```py
#encoding:utf8
from django.core.mail import *

send_mail('Тестовое сообщение', 'Сообщение: поддерживает any символы :D', EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['EMAIL_RECIEVER'])
```